# Java - Looking for sorted MultiMap that implements Navigable

Tags: java, multimap

I'm looking for a data structure like `com.google.common.collect.SortedSetMultimap` which additionally implements the `java.util.NavigableMap` interface.
The map should store multiple values per key, sort the entries by the keys and offer the `java.util.NavigableMap` interface.
Does someone know a library which provides such a data structure?
Apache Collections und Guava Collections doesn't have one.

I know that I could use a `java.util.TreeMap` storing a Collection but a class like `com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap` would be more convenient. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava is...working on it, but maintaining GWT compatibility is making it somewhat problematic.

You can track progress on the Guava issue tracker, [issue 51](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=51).